# Access function defined in separate .js file from a .js file

Tags: javascript, function, loading

I've seen quite a few questions regarding loading a .js file into an HTML file, and I know how to do that. However, say I have the file "classlist.js." How can I go about using the classes defined in that javascript file in another javascript file? I keep seeing answers that suggest using the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filepath"></script>
```

syntax. When used in a .js file, though, it throws a syntax error on the "<" so I assume this code is invalid.

So, how would one utilize a function in a .js file that was defined in a separate .js file... that works, and is efficient (If there is one)?

EDIT:
I'm going to clarify some thing for the future, since I'm still fairly new to Javascript, and it looks like there were a number of other factors I didn't even know came into play.

I had two .js files, one of which declared classes that were extensions of classes in the other file. I wanted to use the extended classes in a webpage, and I thought I had to load the originial classes into the second .js file, THEN load that .js file into the HTML file. I wasn't programming completely outside of HTML.

Sorry for any misunderstanding, hopefully this thread is helpful to somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about javascript in a web browser, all js files are loading in an html file, typically index.html.  You need to use the script tag to load the javascript in the proper order **in that html file**, not in the javascript file.  So if file B requires the things in file A, you need to load file A first, meaning put the script tag that loads file A before the script tag that loads file B.

Answer (score 3):

Two answers:

#### Non Browser

If you're using JavaScript in a non-browser environment (NodeJS, RingoJS, SilkJS, Rhino, or any of a bunch of others), the answer depends on the environment — but many of these use the [CommonJS `require` mechanism](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1). E.g.:

```
// Get access to public symbols in foo.js
var foo = require("foo.js");

// Use the `bar` function exported by foo.js
foo.bar();
```

#### Browser

**If** you're using JavaScript in a browser, you put `script` tags like the one you quoted in the HTML, in the order in which they should be processed (so, scripts relying on things defined in other scripts should be included after the scripts they rely on).

If you want to maximize efficiency in terms of page load time, combine the scripts together on the server (probably also minifying/compressing/packing them) and use just the one `script` tag.

Comment: The OP refers to an HTML file.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: I'm *sure* that wasn't in the first version of this question, must have been added in the five-minute window. In any case, I answered both, just in case. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the reference to `classlist.js` in your HTML file (not your Javascript file), before any other `SCRIPT` element which requires it. For example, within the 'head' element:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="testclass.js"></script>
  <script src="file_using_testclass.js"></script>
  <script>
    var tc = new TestClass();
  </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted above should do the trick however since you mentioned doing it efficiently you can consider taking a look at javascript module based loaders like require js( http://requirejs.org/ ) based on AMD